# How can I replace jquery.js file?

Tags: virus

A virus scan on a PC showed that the file `jquery.js` is containing spyware. But the antivirus program (sophos) can't repair the file. So I think that I want to replace it. I found a file with the same name on https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/test . Is it the file that I need? The file on this github page is only in form of sourcecode. So i would also need to know how to compile it in order to replace the bad file.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Please take the [tour](https://superuser.com/tour) to get your first badge!

Answer (score 2):

[JQuery](http://jquery.com/) has many versions, you need to know which one is used, the complete list can be found [here](https://code.jquery.com/jquery/). You can see the version in the first part of the file.

I doubt that it is a legitimate virus risk, since that `.js` is executed by your browser, and it should securely execute it.

There is a similar [question](https://community.sophos.com/products/endpoint-security-control/f/sophos-endpoint-software/98589/code-jquery-com-blocked-malicious-site-threat-js-refc-gen/358009) in Sophos forum, as well as [here](https://community.sophos.com/products/xg-firewall/f/firewall-and-policies/109122/failing-pci-scans-because-of-outdated-jquery-in-user-portal---is-there-a-fix/390837).

Comment: Javascript malware can steal data from the site it is running from, so it is still a risk. It is essentially an XSS attack.